# An exercise in Rudin's RCA

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Would you please give me some help on the following problem?

Suppose $1 \leq p \leq \infty$, and $q$ is the exponent conjugate to $p$. Suppose $\mu$ is a positive $\sigma$-finite measure and $g$ is a measurable function such that $fg\in L^1(\mu)$ for every $f\in L^p(\mu)$. Prove that then $g\in L^q(\mu)$.

If $p=\infty$. It is obvious that $g\in L^1(\mu)$, so it suffices to consider the case $1\leq p \lt \infty$. I first tried to think of a counterexample by constructing some $g\notin L^q(\mu)$ with $fg\notin L^1$. But since the $\sigma$-finiteness of $\mu$ is given, I think that the proof should rely on the duality of $L^p$ and $L^q$. I guess solving the problem amounts to show that the map $\Psi:L^p \to \mathbb{C}$ defined by $\Psi(f)=\int fg$ is bounded, but I am stuck here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll suggest a brief sketch: Start by assuming that $f \ge 0$.

- Choose sets $E_k$ with $\mu(E_k) < \infty$, $E_k \subseteq E_{k + 1}$, and $X = \bigcup E_k$ by $\sigma$-finiteness. Take $G_n = \{x : |g(x)| < n\}$, and let $$g_n = \chi_{G_n \cap E_k}\cdot g$$ be an indicator function. Note $g_n \in L^q$.
- Define (bounded) linear functionals $\Lambda_{n, k}$ on $L^p$ by
  $$\Lambda_{n, k}(f) = \int g_n f d\mu$$
- If these have a common bound, we're done. If not, use the Banach-Steinhaus theorem to find $f$ for which $$\sup_{n, k} |\Lambda_{n, k} f| = \infty$$ Use the monotone convergence theorem to conclude that $gf \notin L^1$, a contradiction.

Comment: I can't see how this shows that $g$ is in $L^q$. Would you please elaborate more?

Comment: @user.so This shows that $f \mapsto \int fg$ is a bounded linear functional, so the duality result in Rudin's Theorem 6.16 says that there exists an $h \in L^q$ such that $\int fg = \int fh$ for all $f$. Show that $g = h$ pointwise a.e.

Comment: Now I see. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think similarly we might as well just take $g_n=\chi_{G_n\cap E_n}\cdot g$, $\Lambda_n:f\mapsto\lVert g_nf\rVert_1$, so that we can apply MCT directly to these $|g_n|$ (since $|g_n|\to |g|$ pointwisely from below), although in the original argument, we can also just apply MCT along the diagonal $|g_{n,n}|$.

Answer (score 2):

First try the easier problem that if there exists $k > 0$ such that $$\|fg\|_1 \le k \|f\|_p$$ for all $f \in L^p(\mu)$, then $g \in L^q(\mu)$. This is where $\sigma$-finiteness comes in.

Next define sets $$E_k = \left\{ f \in L^p(\mu) : \|fg\|_1 \le k \|f\|_p \right\}.$$ Each $E_k$ is closed and moreover $$L^p(\mu) = \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty E_k.$$ Apply the Baire Category Theorem.

Comment: Okay. Let me follow your proof. The first part follows from the duality of $L^p$ and $L^q$. In the second part, we use the Baire's theorem to conclude that for some $m$, $E_m$ has nonempty interior, say $U$. If $U$ contains $0$, then since $\bigcup_t tU=L^p$, we may conclude that all $f$'s satisfy the inequality in $E_m$ and we are done. But how can we show that the interior of $E_m$ contains $0$?

Comment: Since $E_m$ has an interior point $f_0$ you can show that $\|f\|_p \le 1$ implies $\|fg\|_1 \le M$ (for some larger constant $M$) so that $E_M$ has $0$ as an interior point.